# RSNNS elman network

Tags: r

I am new to R and neural networks . So I trained and predicted an elman network like so :

```
require ( RSNNS )
mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv",header = TRUE)
mydata.train = mydata[1000:7000,]
mydata.test = mydata[800:999,]

fit <- elman ( mydata.train[,2:19],mydata.train[,1], size =100 
     learnFuncParams =c (0.1) , maxit =1000)
pred <-predict (fit , mydata.test[,2:19])
```

so pred contains the predictions . The problem I am having is that 
When I run `pred <-predict (fit , mydata.test[1,2:19])` i.e. on a specific 
data item , it doesn't give me the same prediction as in the previous batch .
Should it not give me the same result ? The weights and everything are set and it should give the same result everytime , no ? Or are the batch predictions somehow depending on each other ?

EDIT : Actually I find that running the predict line several times in a row , the answers are different everytime ! Is this expected ? I am very confused as I thought the weights and biases of the network are set ? Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the `elman` function, invoke
`set.seed(0)`

This will initialize the random number generator and will lead to identical results if you follow the same sequence of commands multiple times.  For a different initialization, call `set.seed(1)` etc.

```
require ( RSNNS )
mydata <- read.csv("mydata.csv",header = TRUE)
mydata.train <- mydata[1000:7000,]
mydata.test <- mydata[800:999,]

set.seed(0)
fit <- elman ( mydata.train[,2:19], mydata.train[,1], size=100, 
               learnFuncParams=c(0.1) , maxit=1000 )

pred <- predict ( fit , mydata.test[,2:19] )
```

Answer (score 0):

An Elman network predicts the output based on the inputs plus the state of a set of hidden units from the previous time step. So the 'memory'of the network just before you use predict is different than just after you use predict.

A trick to reset you're network's memory 'back in time', predict the (training) targets using the inputs from your training sample.

```
require ( RSNNS )
mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv",header = TRUE)
mydata.train = mydata[1000:7000,]
mydata.test = mydata[800:999,]

fit <- elman ( mydata.train[,2:19],mydata.train[,1], size =100 
     learnFuncParams =c (0.1) , maxit =1000)

pred_1 <-predict (fit , mydata.test[,2:19])
resetNet <- predict(fit, mydata.train[,2:19])
pred_2 <-predict (fit , mydata.test[,2:19])
```

`Pred_1` and `Pred_2` should now be the same.